# Start highest unlocked level(scene) on button click

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im new in developing so need some help for my game!
On my game I have 2 buttons one is "Play" and other "Level Select"
I stuck at the "Play" button, need to make a script that is always loading the highest level that is unlocked, not current but highest.
Here is the code that im using for level manager

```
public List<Button> levelButton;
public Sprite lockimage;

public bool delete;

private void Start()
{

    int saveIndex = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SaveIndex");
    for (int i = 0; i < levelButton.Count; i++)
    {


        if (i <= saveIndex)
        {
            levelButton[i].interactable = true;
        }
        else
        {
            levelButton[i].interactable = false;
            levelButton[i].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = lockimage;
        }
    }
}
public void LevelSelect()
{
    int level = int.Parse(EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(level);
}

public void PlayGame()
{

    //code here

}

public void ResetGame()
{

    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveIndex", 0);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(0);

}

public void DontResetGame()
{

    SceneManager.LoadScene(0);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
 SceneManager.LoadScene(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SaveIndex"));
```

edit: adding some info/context.

I realized that you set level buttons interactivity on the start functions based on  the int save_index value you get from PlayerPrefs.

From there, I assumed that you could load the level directly using that same value on the PlayGame function.

Do note that the code I wrote will throw an error, if the "SaveIndex" key is not yet on PlayerPrefs

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @ysf, edited my answer with some more info.

Comment: the code works but it loads me wrong level... in build settings I use mainmenu as 0 , and all others level scenes as 1,2,3,4,5..... when i clear playerprefs,the play button are not load the "level_01" scene, and when some levels are unlocked it plays me one scene down, like level 5 is unlocked when i press play it start from level 4... any suggestions ?

Comment: oh I figured it out, and its working now... Thanks alot dude for your help!